# Distinguish between invokations of onStartCommand

Tags: android, service

I am writing a Recording service, that gets additional data in the intent and function appropriately. i use START_REDELIVER_INTENT so that on every start command i start the recording with the same settings i have on the original intent, But i must know if the current invokation of onStartCommand is due to explicit startService or a process crash.

so my question is How to distinguish between an invokation of onStartCommand that came as a result of a startService request, and a onStartCommand invokation that the system invoked after the service has crashed\closed without explicit stopSelf\stopService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the flags parameter to onStartCommand.

If it is 0, it is a "normal" start.

If the flags contain START_FLAG_REDELIVERY, then it is a re-delivered intent after the service was killed and restarted.

If the flags contain START_FLAG_RETRY, then it is an intent that is re-tried, presumably after a crash but there may be other circumstances.